# Umbraco Custom DataType with number input not showing value

Tags: angularjs, binding, model, umbraco

I've got a custom data type in Umbraco 7.4.3 which has a simple input of type *number*.  This is bound to the model using the *ng-bind* attribute, but the textbox does not render the value.

**NumberTestInput.Editor.html**

```
<div ng-controller="NumberTestInput.NumberTestInputController">
    <!--Changing the type to 'text' causes the value to render correctly-->
    <!--Otherwise, it renders with an empty value-->
    <input type="number" ng-model="model.value" />
</div>
```

**NumberTestInput.Controller.js**

```
angular.module("umbraco").controller("NumberTestInput.NumberTestInputController", function ($scope) {

    //Causes value to load on page load, but textbox is blanked out again after publishing
    //$scope.model.value = parseInt($scope.model.value);

});
```

**package.manifest**

```
{
  "propertyEditors": [
    {
      "name": "Number Test Input",
      "alias": "numberTestInput",
      "editor": {
        "hideLabel": false,
        "isReadOnly": false,
        "valueType": "INT",
        "view": "~/App_Plugins/NumberTestInput/NumberTestInput.Editor.html"
      }
    }
  ],
  "javascript": [
    "~/App_Plugins/NumberTestInput/NumberTestInput.Controller.js"
  ]
}
```

It looks like an issue with model value type being set to string instead of a number, though I've got this setup in the manifest as an INT, and the values are saved correctly when input.  It's just that they do not render correctly in the UI.  Is there something I need to do differently to get this working?

Comment: What's the value of `model.value` actually?

Comment: @developer033 It's a numeric value.  The value itself is being stored correctly, as proven by changing the textbox type to "text" from "number".

Answer (score 0):

Found a hack to work around this, by creating a new property to wrap *model.value* and forcing it to return an integer.

**Add to controller**

```
Object.defineProperty(
    $scope,
    "modelValue",
    {
        get: function() { return parseInt($scope.model.value); },
        set: function(newValue) { $scope.model.value = newValue; }
    });
```

**View**

```
<input type="number" ng-model="modelValue" />
```

The number input field is now bound to the new *modelValue* property which returns the value of *model.value* as an integer.

This does feel like a hack though, and hopefully there is a better way of doing this where Umbraco can set the correct type automatically.